# Transparency with JPEGs

Tags: png, jpeg, transparency

JPEGs are smaller in size than PNGs. So, I thought that if I can make a specific region in a JPEG-file transparent, with some code, maybe I can save some bytes.

So does anyone know how to achieve this with for example PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: No. JPEGs do not support transparency.

Comment: JPEGs are also smaller than PNGs because JPEG uses lossy compression, and PNG uses lossless compression.

Comment: You can at least reduce size of PNGs with tranparency using [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) ([GUI](http://pngmini.com)).

Comment: If i retrieve a png image, it coming fine so can i change that to JPEG using java script. Is it possible ?

Comment: Here's a description about how to maintain jpeg compression with png transparency:
http://peterhrynkow.com/how-to-compress-a-png-like-a-jpeg/

Comment: Ye, that's what I needed at the time! Already stumbled upon it myself as well.

Answer (score 8):

No. You can't do this. JPGs do not support alpha channels and have no capacity to designate certain colors as transparent either (GIF-style).

Answer (score 5):

There's several issues with this, all of them have to do with that JPEG is a lossy compression format. The JPEG format is optimized for natural images and sharp edges will get blurred. If you intend that a specific pixel should have the value #d67fff there's no guarantee that after color conversion, FDCT, quantization, IDCT and color conversion, the pixel still will have that value. There's also a strong possibility that that pixel value will occur in areas that you don't want.

Comment: It was something like this I was looking for at the time; http://peterhrynkow.com/how-to-compress-a-png-like-a-jpeg/

Answer (score 2):

No.  JPEG does not support transparency and is not likely to do so any time
soon. http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-12.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, the client renders the image and doesn't know that you want it to treat that color as transparent (plus various compression methods on jpeg wouldn't work well with transparencies anyway).

I believe you can go with an 8-bit custom-pallet png, should save you a lot of space. Otherwise 24-bit PNG is your only high color option.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to SVG containing a color information as JPEG and an alpha channel as grayscale mask. Here is a tool I wrote to do it https://github.com/igrmk/transpeg